# Blackberry : Reading SQLite DB when Media Card Encryption is enabled

Tags: sqlite, encryption, blackberry

My application packages a pre-existing SQLite file as a resource, which it stores at //sdcard/databases/[appName]/db.sql.

My problem is when users have their devices set to encrypt the Media Card, I can put the file on the card but my app cannot access it or decrypt it, and therefore I'm unable to use it.

Is there a way I have my app decrypt the .sql file, or prevent it from encrypting on the card in the first place? This seems like it could be a common use case.